# Find the row a number parameter belongs to in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pseudocode

I'm trying to create a pseudo code to find the row a number parameter belongs to, for example if the parameter is 2 I will get Price modifier 10 because 2 is in the range of Minimum Qty 1 but less than 5, if the parameter is 5 I will get Price modifier 8 because the the Minimum qty is 5. How can I achieve this but based on the Minimum Qty not in the parameter?

[image]

For example if numParam is 2, and I want to get Price Modifier 10. Find row where Minimum Qty is >= than 2 and Minimum Qty <= 2?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a maximum QTY in your table. But what you can do is find the first record with the lowest minimumQTY like:

```
select top 1 pricemod from [tablewithdata] where minimumQty < @param1 order by minimumQty asc
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Ralf de Kleine

Comment: No thanks Pedro! If this answer works for you font forget te mark it as the answer (V button left of the answer).